# sql 2012 ssis All Executions report not showing anything

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working on **migrating a SQL 2008 SSIS package to SQL 2012**. After upgrading and loading the package, I scheduled it.

**The job fails and the error says**

> 'Package execution on IS Server failed. Execution ID: 20, Execution
>   Status:4.  To view the details for the execution, right-click on the
>   Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report'

When I open the report as instructed, it shows me zeroes for all `columns - 0 failed, 0 running, 0 succeeded, 0 others`. I clicked on the filter and it is applying only a date; changing the date to encompass the past year and next month, nothing appears.

This is my first experience with SQL 2012 and the Integration Services reports.

Am I missing something to find the execution details?

Comment: Are you using a proxy account to execute the package in the job?  Does the proxy account have file system access on the server?

Comment: Eric - yes, I am using a proxy account. I do not know if it has file system access, is that necessary for displaying the execution count in the report?

Comment: I don't know.  I suspect that the package execution is not being logged because the proxy account is failing to start the package altogether.  This is usually related to permissions.

Comment: The package starts because I ran SQL Profiler which shows some of the queries running against the database successfully until it fails.

Comment: Have you tried launching the 2012 package manually?

Comment: The package launches fine locally in BIDS VS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

What happened to me was an issue with the date filters. SSMS was defaulting the date filters of the All Executions report to end at the current date, 2016-11-28. However, in the server's time zone, the date was 2016-11-29. Apparently even though these filters appear to default based on your desktop's time zone, they are applied using the server's time zone. I was able to get the missing executions to appear by changing the date filter to include 'tomorrow'.